# Understanding Python stat.st_ctime on WINDOWS

Tags: python, windows, file

Following script creates a text file and tries to change `stat.st_ctime` in different ways:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import platform
import time
import os.path

print(platform.platform())
print(platform.machine())
print(platform.python_version())

fn = 'Hanswurst.txt'
if os.path.exists(fn):
    print('Leaving. File already exist.')
    quit()

file = open(fn, 'w')
file.close()
print('\nCreation time:')
print(time.ctime(os.stat(fn).st_ctime))

time.sleep(3)

os.utime(fn, None)
print('\nCreation time after call of utime. I guess this is ok:')
print(time.ctime(os.stat(fn).st_ctime))

time.sleep(3)

file = open(fn, 'w')
file.write('Hanswurst is dead.')
file.close()
print('\nBut also after another file with the same name is created ctime stays the same:')
print(time.ctime(os.stat(fn).st_ctime))

time.sleep(3)

os.remove(fn)
print('\nFile does exist?', os.path.exists(fn))
file = open(fn, 'w')
file.write('Hanswurst is dead.')
file.close()
print('\nEven if the file is deleted before ctime stays the same:')
print(time.ctime(os.stat(fn).st_ctime))

os.remove(fn)
```

On my Windows 7 machine 64 bit Python 3.2 creates followng output:

```
Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
AMD64
3.2.5

Creation time:
Tue Jan 28 12:58:44 2014

Creation time after call of utime. I guess this is ok:
Tue Jan 28 12:58:44 2014

But also after another file with the same name is created ctime stays the same:
Tue Jan 28 12:58:44 2014

File does exist? False

Even if the file is deleted before ctime stays the same:
Tue Jan 28 12:58:44 2014
```

Why is `stat.st_ctime` never changed? This is even true if I start the script again afterwards. What would I have to do to change it?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in python or windows.